# Buscar valor inteiro no BD

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa tarde, estou tentando consultar um valor inteiro no meu BD e guardar o mesmo numa variável, tentei desta maneira:

```
$procuraPreco = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT preco FROM infs WHERE seis='$seis' and bin='$bin' and quantidade='$qndtd'");
print_r($retornaPreco = mysqli_fetch_all($procuraPreco,MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

O array está retornando vazio.
Sei que possa ser uma possível duplicada mas já tentei de muitas formas e não consegui

Comment: Printa sua sql, pra ver se as variaveis estão preenchidas corretas. Pq o nome dessa variavel `$qndtd` está um pouco estranha, as vezes era pra ser `$qntd` e vc errou

Comment: Printa a consulta e testa pra ver se tens retorno de resultados dela, se possível adicione a estrutura sql e o echo da consulta para que possamos testar.

Comment: Já consegui. Era um erro de variável mesmo, obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Creio eu que possa ser sua consulta usando variáveis php. Ficaria assim:

$procuraPreco = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT preco FROM infs WHERE seis='".$seis."' and bin='".$bin."' and quantidade='".$qndtd."';");
print_r($retornaPreco = mysqli_fetch_all($procuraPreco,MYSQLI_ASSOC));

Comment: Esse não é o problema